# WPF setting Brush from ResourceDictionary to a property in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, resourcedictionary

I'm making a View with buttons and I want to change their color on click.
I want the buttons to have a default color,and on first click will change their color to another.

In order to do so, I wanted to keep it clean so, I saved the brush in a resourceDictionary.

```
<ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WeekCalendarDefaultCellColor" Color="#FFE5CC"/>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WeekCalendarClickCellColor" Color="#FFFF00"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

for MVVM, I bind my button brush to a property (if I set a color by myself the binding works, but I want to use the same colors in the whole application so I think its better to take it from the dictionary)

```
public SolidColorBrush CurrentBrush =//????;
```

Now I want to insert the Brush from my dictionary to this property, how can I fetch the Brush from the Dictionary to the view model?

Thanks in advance to all the helpers !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get Brushes from Resource Dictionary and apply it to an element dynamicallly in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152803/how-get-brushes-from-resource-dictionary-and-apply-it-to-an-element-dynamicallly)

Comment: "I want to use the same colors in the whole application so I think its better to take it from the dictionary". no. the reverse is true: want to use the same colors in the whole application -> put them to the resources / resource dictionary

Comment: MVVM does not mean "shove all my UI code into view models".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code would work if you use it in code behind:

```
button.Background = (Brush)FindResource("ButtonNormalBackgroundBrush");
```

BUT! You are saying you want to make it clean.

> for MVVM, I bind my button brush to a property

You should not bind button brush to VM property. Brush is GUI (View in MVVM) part. VM should contain kind of state, like bool or enum, etc. Than you could read this state in button style and use triggers to change background.

Comment: why resort to code-behind?? `Background="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackgroundBrush}"`

Comment: Yes, you are right. He was just asking about accessing ResourceDictionary in VM to solve his problem. I just wanted to point out that this is easly possible in CodeBehind, but as I said, this is still not good enough solution. In this case, Bindings with Triggers and than, as you pointed, StaticResources.